# How to identify, video has reached to last slide or certain period. using JW player with RTMP VOD

Tags: video, jwplayer, rtmp, wowza

How to identify, User has finished watching RTMP video,
I have a requirement to trigger a function, after watching a complete video.

I'm using JW Player with RTMP video on demand (Wowza VOD) streaming.

Answer (score 0):

JwPlayer script has inbuild events, like, .setup, .onError, .onReady,.onComplete, as described below.

```
jwplayer('#videoBox').setup({
        file: videoFile,
        image: "/path/to/image/videoslogo.png",                        
        rtmp: {
            securetoken: "123456789ABCD"
        },
        width: "80%",
        aspectratio: "21:9"
 });
//onError, Show a alert box
jwplayer('#videoBox').onError ( function(event) { 
                    alert("Sorry for an inconvenience, Something went wrong, Please create a ticket, Thanks.");
});
//On Ready, play after 2000 milli seconds
jwplayer('#videoBox').onReady ( function(event) {
        setTimeout(function() {
           jwplayer('#videoBox').play(true);
        },2000);
})
// on Complete, Change Lecture status and Assign Next entities
jwplayer('#videoBox').onComplete( function(event) {
   //Trigger required function here
});
```

Hope it may helpful to someone.
Thanks